# Edit some elements in c# list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to edit some elements in a list (called `treeNodes`):

```
List<TreeNodeViewModel> treeNodes = GetAllTreeNodes();

foreach (var item in role.Privileges)
{
    TreeNodeViewModel treeNode = treeNodes.Single(tn => tn.id == item.Id.ToString());
    treeNode.state.IsChecked = true;
}
```

But once the `treeNode.state.IsChecked = true;` is executed, all list items will have `IsChecked = true`, why is that? It should edit the selected item only.

Comment: it looks like a deep copy issue. do you assign one `state` variable to every node?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "selected item"? You do that for _all_ `Privileges`, did you intend that?

Comment: I did treeNode.state = new NodeStateViewModel(false, false, false, true); and solved the issue

Comment: Maybe the issue is deep copy, I'm reading about it now

Comment: I had this problem once. I assigned the same instance to one property of every object of a list in a loop. Result: when you change one -> you change all of them. This is why calling `new` solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did treeNode.state = new NodeStateViewModel(false, false, false, true); and solved the issue